# What are the speed comparisons of NDB vs DB (on High Replication Datastore)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Taken from the [Python NDB Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/overview#writes):

> When the application reads an entity, that entity is *automatically cached;* this gives fast (and inexpensive) reads for frequently-read entities.
>
> ...
>
> The NDB function that writes the data (for example, put()) returns after the cache invalidation; the Apply phase happens *asynchronously.*

In watching on Youtube, [Google I/O 2011: More 9s Please: Under The Covers of the High Replication Datastore](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO015C3R6dw), at 13:11-ish, the average latencies are:

> **Master/Slave:**
>
> - Read: *15ms*
> - Write: *20ms*
>
> **High Replication:**
>
> - Read: *15ms*
> - Write: ***45ms***

How significantly does NDB affect these speeds, from the app's perspective?

**Edit:** Specifically curious about timing stats (in milliseconds).

*Extra Credit:* I've also heard Nick Johnson refer to queries taking around *160ms* each (in 2009) [`[link]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1023799/1302400) Does NDB provide any speed benefits on queries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using NDB makes your datastore calls appear, from your app's perspective, significantly faster.

READ: Best case scenario, reads are made from instance cache or memcache. In most cases, this will be significantly faster than reading from datastore.

WRITE: The NDB put/write method returns right after the cache invalidation. This is way faster than a normal write. So from your app's perspective, it's quite faster. The actual write, however, is performed asynchronously.

NDB vs DB (High Replication): In terms of speed from your app's perspective, NDB should be a clear win.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm specifically interested in the timing, in milliseconds. Editing the post to reflect that now. :)

Comment: @wTyeRogers If you want to know exact figures, you'll have to do your own benchmarks.

Comment: @NickJohnson, awesome; thanks! Since this is my first Stack Overflow post, I have a question regarding etiquette that's not in the FAQ: Do I edit Albert's post to include the stats, or do I post my own individual answer? (It just feels a bit odd to post an answer to my own question..)

Comment: @wTyeRogers If the answer has substantial new information, answer your own question - that's perfectly acceptable behaviour on SO. If you think it's just a minor tweak, feel free to edit an existing answer.

Answer (score 18):

You'll have to benchmark for yourself -- times depend on many factors, like entity size and complexity: more properties or more items in repeated properties -> more complex.

The numbers you quote are really old and probably no longer reflect reality; most users' experience is that HRD is not slower than M/S, on average (in part because M/S has much higher variability).

There were some NDB benchmarks done here: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=118 -- but it doesn't compare the numbers to old db.

You can use Appstats to quickly do some timing of operations in a real app.

Comment: Good to know for my first Stack Overflow post! I was secretly hoping that _you_ would be one of the responders, given your intimate knowledge of NDB and your ability to analyze stats to death with your X-Ray vision of Python --a deadly combination for this question. _Thank you_ for highlighting some of the complexity points, and the link is very helpful.